# SQL Server performance questions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, performance-testing, query-performance

I have this query in SQL Server 2012:

```
Select cat, dog, ant, pig, ItemId 
from dbo.Animals 
where cat <> 'sam' 
  and cat in ('bam', 'dam') 
order by pig
```

I have laid out below what I did and looked at execution plan and the performance time below.

1. No indexing -  Table scan - 20 s
2. Clustered Index on ItemId -    Clustered Index scan - 20 s
3. Non Clustered index on cat -  Clustered Index scan [ Same as 2 ] - 20s
4. Non Clustered index on pig -  Clustered Index scan [ Same as 2 ] - 20s

My questions is why is the performance the same in all scenarios?

Is Caching playing a factor ? I don't have permission to play with freeing cache and things like that currently. Can I try anything else from indexing perspective ?

Comment: How large are the tables?  How many rows match the conditions?

Comment: How **big** is the table, e.g. how many **rows** does it hold? Typically, on fairly small tables, going to the length of index lookups etc. isn't worth the trouble - SQL Server just scans the whole table

Comment: Table has 1.1 million . Query returns 899k results

Comment: this would be a scenario where you need to look at the query diagram to see what it is doing; also, what are the data types? if the columns are `nvarchar`, then a match against `'sam'` is suboptimal - you should be comparing to `N'sam'`, for example

Comment: if you're returning 899k results, I imagine most of the time is bandwidth, and the "query time" you're measuring is actually data transfer time; this won't change regardless of whether the query took 20ms, 200ms, or 800ms; what does `set statistics time on` show if you run the query?

Comment: (899005 row(s) affected)
Table 'Test'. Scan count 1, logical reads 58896, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 4344 ms,  elapsed time = 19008 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think i see what you are saying. The CPU time is actually changing after the set statistics time on on all my scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` is redundant, because the conditions on `cat` only need the `in`.

I suspect the index can be used for the `where` clause but not for the `order by`.  Hence, indexes can be used to optimize the search for the rows, but not for the final ordering.  Presumably there is a large amount of data and that is taking the bulk of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your where clause observation. This was my error while mocking up a hypothetical question. I tried to force the query to use the Non Clustered index on cat which was slower than the original